# Adding options to store of component not working properly extjs 6

Tags: extjs

I have a component with an extjs (version 6) combo. I want to dynamically modify the store to add more options in a component that extends the component with the combo. I tried several ways:

```
component.store.add({'OPTION_ONE_START_RENDER': 'OPTION_ONE_START_RENDER'});
component.store.add(['OPTION_ONE_START_RENDER', 'OPTION_ONE_START_RENDER']);
component.store.add({ display: 'OPTION_ONE_START_RENDER', value: 'OPTION_ONE_START_RENDER', name: 'OPTION_ONE_START_RENDER' });
component.store.add({ name: 'OPTION_ONE_START_RENDER' , value: 'OPTION_ONE_START_RENDER'});
```

but I get the options but not visible (option one, two and three come from the parent component), the newly added options are below, but they do not show up correctly (they capture some space, but it's like the display text is not getting rendered):

[image: Dynamically added options not showing up]

I have tried adding the options before render, after render, and when defining the component but I always get the same result and I can't figure out the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure at what timing you are trying to add the data.
If you extend from an another component, this component needs it's own store (so best to do this in a viewmodel).

Once you extend, the store has to be created and this might be best on init or you specify a `load` listener and add the records at that time.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/327i)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to [reload](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load) the store?
I've tried in this way and working

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
        data : [
            {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
            {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
            {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        ]
    });
    
    var mycomponent = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        store: states,
        id : "componentid",
        queryMode: 'local',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
                '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{abbr} - {name}</li>',
            '</tpl></ul>'
        ),
        // template for the content inside text field
        displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '{abbr} - {name}',
            '</tpl>'
        )
    });
    
    var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text    : 'Add new select',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler : function() {
       var mycomp = Ext.getCmp("componentid");
       var mydata = mycomp.getStore().add({abbr: 'RO', name: "Romania"});
    }
});
    
});
```

Try also [loadData](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html?#method-loadData). Get current data from the component.
Let's say var `myData = myComponent.getStore().data.items` and add your new data in myData array. After that you shoud reload the store with the new data using `myComponent.store.loadData(myData)`